# "Created From" is a required value. when adding a new customer

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database

Everytime I attempt to add a new customer via the admin panel I am stopped in my tracks by the error

> "Created From" is a required value.

Looking at all the available options to fill, this is not one of the options.

Now looking at the Database I can see it is in the eav_attribute table:

[image: erroranous field]

I have not added any custom attribute to the customer for admin. So, must be a default system attribute. Now, I was wondering why this attribute ain't showing up in the admin=> add new customer ? I haven't made any changes to admin.

Is there a way I can get this to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely this attribute was set as required in the database, and after testing against 3 fresh databases of magento 1.9.3.7. I overcame this by changing it to not be a required field.